# mongoosedb expires property not expiring

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've created a Schema which contains this property:

```
expire: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: 60
}
```

When a new document is created it successfully sets the expire field to the current datetime.

No index is created on the collection.

I subsequently added

```
model.on('index',function(err){
    console.log('index created');
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Neither logs are occuring.

So I'm assuming that mongoose is not even attempting to create the ttl index on the collection, but I don't see why not. Am I missing a step? am I meant to create the index myself? the mongoose docs seem to imply that mongoose handles creation of the index.

Comment: how are you creating the index?

Comment: This is the question. Am I meant to do it myself? The mongoose docs state that the index is created when you use the expires property so I haven't tried to create an index myself.

Comment: check that the indexes have been created in the db - run this in your mongo shell `db.yourdb.getIndexes()` 
When changing the indexes you have to manually delete it in the collection before the new one will take effect.

Comment: Thanks but I did state in the question that no index has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoosejs does indeed handle the creation of the index as suspected.  In order to find the problem I added an ensureIndexes call as follows:

```
model.ensureIndexes(function (err) {
    console.log('ensure index', err)
})
```

This then showed that one of the existing indexes (unique email addresses) was failing because of existing documents in the DB which were not unique.

Fixing this problem the above code then works fine. Hope this helps anyone else who runs into problems with mongoose TTL.